# Why does rand() produce integers with difference of 3 or 4?

Tags: c, random, c99

I read that `rand()` generates the same number when not seeded. So, I added `srand()` and i fed it with **unity spaced integers**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        srand(i);
        printf("%d ",rand());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the result was predictable.

```
38 41 45 48 51 54 58 61 64 68
```

The results had a difference of 3 or 4. I tried the same for the interval `-9 to 0`. The results were predictable again..!

```
9 12 15 19 22 25 28 32 35 38
```

Why is it that `rand()` generates such numbers..?

Why does `srand(0)` always lead to `38` and `srand(1)` always lead to `41` and so on..?

Comment: You are only supposed to seed it once.

Comment: Because you shouldn't call `srand` within the loop....

Comment: @MitchWheat: `rand` is implementation defined. Why would you expect your results to match OP’s? And, no, you are not “supposed” to call `srand` only one. You are supposed to call `srand` to seed a new sequence. OP wished to examine multiple sequences, so they used multiple seeds.

Comment: Because those are the first numbers your implementation of `rand()` produces from those seeds.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Using `srand` within the loop was necessary and appropriate for OP’s stated goal: Examining the behavior of `srand` in response to `rand`. This code is not their production code for using `rand`; it is their exploratory code for examining the behavior of `rand` and `srand`. Furthermore, the fact that they called `srand` repeatedly is **not** the cause of the generated numbers incrementing by three. That is a property of the particular `srand` and `rand` implementation, revealing that it does little processing with the seed.

Comment: @ Eric Postpischil  : you know what I meant.

Comment: "38 41 45 48 51 54 58 61 64 68"  looks a shade more random than [9 9 9 9 9 9](http://ardiri.com/blog/secure_number_generator_for_the_arduino)

Comment: @Sagar Devanand What compiler are you using?

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- it is *exactly* the cause of the numbers incrementing by three *because of the property of the particular* `srand`. The *semi-random* distribution is apparently generated with the first term incremented by `3`. Re-initializing the distribution and printing the first value returned each trip through the loop is producing the values seen exactly because there is little processing of the seed. None of which is contrary to what I wrote in my comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as true randomness in computer systems, the `rand()` function will create a pseudo-random number based on some mathematical formulas that use a seeded initial value and then the state left after each subsequent `rand()` call.

You only have to seed it once (only call `srand()` once in the entire program).

That being said, `rand()` will generate the same sequence of results based on a given seed. If you give it the same seed every time, it will generate the same sequence every time.

For it to work properly, you need to use a different seed every time you run the program. Using `time()` as seed is a popular choice.

Comment: Re “There is no such thing as true randomness in computer systems”: Some processors, including mainstream Intel processors, collect entropy from thermal noise and/or other sources specifically to make it available for random number generation, and some software collects noise from environmental inputs, for the same reason.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know, you can use sensors as source for your seed, including a microphone to capture ambience noise (I believe random.org claims to use that method). But technically it's still not random, it's data from a source.

Comment: The physics community awaits your paper demonstrating the universe is in fact deterministic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's complex but certainly not random, everything happens for a reason, or thousands of them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The majority view amongst physicists currently is that the universe is deterministic. But that is not particularly relevant to this question

Comment: @M.M: The lack of any random chance is [superdeterminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeterminism), and it is not the prevailing model in physics. Probabilistic models are much more favored.

Answer (score 1):

`rand` is notorious for being not very well implemented in some C implementations. It is conceivable the generator does very little work with the seed to produce the next value of `rand()`.

You should look at the second number of each sequence and see if they have a similar pattern. If so, the implementation may be using a     [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

You might want to avoid using the built-in `srand` and `rand` and look for alternatives such as Unix’ `srandom` and `random`.

Comment: A good, fast (but not cryptographically-secure) PRNG with a C reference implementation that’s easy to find is xorshift+.